# Как скопировать файлы с симлинками через ssh?

Tags: unix, shell

Пытаюсь через ssh на удаленном хостинге скопировать папки и файлы из одной директории в другую, но симлинки не копируются. Как мне осуществить копирование вместе с со всеми симлинками? Система MacOS.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сохранения симлинков надо использовать `rsync` с опцией `-a`:

```
# на конце исходной папки нужно ставить /, иначе
# скопируется сама папка, а не содержимое
rsync -a /path/to/source/ /path/to/destination
```

Симлинки, которые указывали на абсолютный путь, продолжат указывать на него же. Симлинки, которые указывали на относительный путь, опять же, продолжат указывать на относительный (т.е. будут указывать на файл уже в новой папке).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd /source/dir/
$ cp -r -L * /distanation/dir/
```

Comment: увы, не помогло. :(

Comment: @BenjaminButton: хм. для mac os ключи для cp могут отличаться. 
`cp -R -L * /distanation/dir/` - может так?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /source/dir/ && tar -cf - * | ( cd /destination/dir/ && tar -xf - )
```

Comment: IMHO лучше `cd /source && tar -cf - ./dir | ( cd /destination && tar -xf - )` т.к. 1) в destination dir может и отсутсвовать 2) `*` не сопоставляется с файлами, которые начинаются с точки...

Answer (score 0):

В Linux

```
sudo cp -a /source/dir /destination
```

(выполнение от root сохранит пользователей, группы и т.п.)

А в MAC смотрите `man cp` (возможно там так же).